# VBA Error 52 to read last line of log file

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to open a log file, and read the last line, to see if the file was correctly closed last time or not. If not, it will add a line in the log specifying a "Fatal Error". But, when the code runs, I get an Error 52 message. I already read a lot of posts here and other foruns, changed my code and used some posted here to make it work, but nothing worked.

Edited to better MCVE:

```
Public Function WriteLogFile(strMsg As String)

Const LogFileName As String = "\log\FrenteCaixa.log"

Dim FileNum As Integer, strLogMsg As String, strAddFatalError As String
FileNum = FreeFile

If Right(strMsg, 6) = "aberto" Then
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & LogFileName For Input Access Read Lock Read As #FileNum
        Dim lngCounter As Long, strLastLine As String
        lngCounter = 0
        Do Until EOF(lngCounter) **--> THE ERROR IS HERE!**
            Line Input #FileNum, strLastLine
            If Left(strLastLine, 8) <> "<!-- EoF" Then strAddFatalError = "<!-- FATAL ERROR -->"
            lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
        Loop
    Close #FileNum
End If

Open ThisWorkbook.Path & LogFileName For Append As #FileNum
If strAddFatalError <> "" Then Print #FileNum, strAddFatalError
Print #FileNum, strLogMsg
Close #FileNum

End Function
```

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in the code above?

Comment: Does LogFileName contain a leading backslash "\" ?

Comment: Check to make sure that the path and filename is correct.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping Best guess: It doesn't. Was just about to comment on that. (Generally, the VBA error messages aren't that cryptic. Just somewhat unspecific at times. But `Error 52: Bad file name or number` seems pretty clear...)

Comment: Do not have `On Error Resume Next`. Yes, the file path have the backslash and is correct. The code to open and write the file is working perfectly, only does not work for reading.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52721678/edit) into your question: At what line do you encounter the error? Generally, if you want to make it easy for people to help you, try generating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now your code snippet as is won't even compile on our machines, let alone exhibit the same behavior as for you.

Comment: Done. Posted the entire code of the function. Its called when de file is opened. Marked the line where the error occurs. In the debugging mode, it indicates that `lngCounter = 0`, so I guess it stops on the first run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `EOF(lngCounter)` is wrong. From its documentation, this function expects a file number:

```
Function EOF(FileNumber As Integer) As Integer
```

You are feeding it with a line counter, which is 0 at the start. This might be the reason for the error you are seeing.

Try replacing `EOF(lngCounter)` with `EOF(FileNum)` and see if it works.

---

Also, if I'm not mistaken, you don't need that line counter `lngCounter` at all here. Reading a line via `Line Input` will advance the line pointer so that the next time the statement is executed, it will read the next line.

```
Public Sub WriteLogFile(strMsg As String)

    Const LogFileName As String = "\log\FrenteCaixa.log"

    Dim FileNum As Integer, strLogMsg As String, strAddFatalError As String
    FileNum = FreeFile

    If Right(strMsg, 6) = "aberto" Then
        Open ThisWorkbook.Path & LogFileName For Input Access Read Lock Read As #FileNum
        Dim strLastLine As String
        Do Until EOF(FileNum)                 '**--> THE ERROR IS HERE!**
            Line Input #FileNum, strLastLine
            If Left(strLastLine, 8) <> "<!-- EoF" Then strAddFatalError = "<!-- FATAL ERROR -->"
        Loop
        Close #FileNum
    End If

    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & LogFileName For Append As #FileNum
    If strAddFatalError <> "" Then Print #FileNum, strAddFatalError
    Print #FileNum, strLogMsg
    Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

I've also made it a `Sub` as you're not assigning any return value, so having it as a function would be somewhat misleading.